# How do I transfer iOS apps only from an old computer to a new one?

Tags: iphone, ipad, data-synchronization, macbook-pro

I've recently bought a MacBook Pro. I've migrated all the iTunes music across from my old pc to my new mac and have also downloaded more tunes since I bought my computer.

Now I'm trying to sync my iPhone and iPad with the new computer - however if I sync them then I lose all the apps.

so is there a way of just migrating the apps across from the old to the new computer. Both my iPad and iPhone are backed up on iCloud - I thought this meant it would automatically download to the MacBook as well, Does it not?

Answer (score 1):

When you choose to backup on iCloud you are creating a backup in the cloud, not the MacBook.

You have the choice to Sync to a computer or to iCloud. If you sync to a computer you can also sync over WiFi, which could be the better option for you by the sound of your question.

If you open iTunes, make sure that it is authorised to your account.

Plug your device in.

It will then say. (substitue iPod for iPhone, iPad etc)

[image]

Click "Transfer Purchases"

Your device will now transfer all the apps and data to this new computer before it syncs the new data.